# How remove popup of basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

Does anybody know how to 'hide' popup message from basic authentication without removing possibility to login in the next way: 'http://username:password@example.com/'

Answer (score 1):

Configure your spring like that.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                    .csrf()
                .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/user")   // rest api
                    //.usernameParameter("username")
                    //.passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    //.logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                    //.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "CSRF-TOKEN")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/#/dashboard/home").permitAll()
                ;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the browser popup logon message if WWW-Authenticate was send by the server. Remove this header from your server that popup will not appear.

Comment: Yes, I've tried but it still exists. And the login with  'http://username:password@example.com/'stoped working